# Unity - Math question about Vector calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, calculation

i am looking for the mathematical formula for the following problem (in 3 dimensional space, so it is about 3 dimensional vectors). I am programming in Unity - GameEngine (C#)

In the first picture you can see my current result. I create 2 vectors (red spheres) and automatically generate an anchor point (green in the picture). this anchor point is always generated "behind" the 2nd vector (on a straight line). The two vectors are always the current and the immediately previous vector.
My current calculation (first picture) looks like this:

```
 Vector3 direction = newVector.position - previousVector.position;
 Vector3 newAnchor.position = newVector.position + direction;
```

What i need is shown in the 2nd picture. I want the anchor point (green) (relative to the direction of the two vectors) to be generated always 90 degrees "to the right" of the 2nd vector. however, i can't derive the mathematical calculation for that.

Hopefully I could describe with the pictures what I try to achieve.

*First picture:*

[image: First picture:]

*Second picture:*

[image: Second picture:]

Comment: So you want to rotate `direction` by 90 degrees before adding it to `newVector.position`.

Comment: yes, i think this could be a solution. rotate around the 2. vector

Comment: You can try direction = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * (-direction); Then add direction to newVector.position. But the result will be offset by the magnitude of the direction vector. You can then change its magnitude as it seems you always want the anchor to be the same length away. BTW if the points on XZ plane then you must use Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0).

Answer (score 1):

### 2D

In order to rotate a vector by 90 degrees all you have to do is **switch** the x and y components and **negate** one of them. You can make extension methods, which allows you to call `vector.Left()` & `vector.Right()` directly on the vector.

```
public static class VectorX
{
    public static Vector2 Left(this Vector2 v)
    {
        return new Vector2(-v.y, v.x);
    }

    public static Vector2 Right(this Vector2 v)
    {
        return new Vector2(v.y, -v.x);
    }
}
```

### 3D

You can use the [Cross Product](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html), which returns a vector that is perpendicular to the other two.

```
var right = Vector3.Cross(forward, up).normalized;
```

So if you give the forward vector and the up vector of a point you will receive a vector pointing to the right. You can negate it if you want it pointing left.

Comment: that would only work if he needs to rotate it for  90°, but OP wants the vectors rotation to be perpendicular to the previous vector

Comment: @nka_Zz great point, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am guessing you want to basically find a particle that is in the same direction as the vector in front of it and then have it be perpendicular to the vector at a unit distance.

I suggest using a raycast forward to that vector with a required or a capsule cast.

here is the pseudocode i suggest

```
        public void FixedUpdate()
        {
//https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CapsuleCast.html please use whatever overload you find comfortable 
                   if (Physics.CapsuleCast(p1, p2, charContr.radius, transform.forward, out hit, 10))
    {
                        distanceToObstacle = hit.distance;
               // Then get the ortho to the vector of the using cross product 
             Vector3 direction = newVector.position - previousVector.position;
             Vector3 right = -(Vector3.Cross(direction, Vector3.up).normalized);
             
             // now you have the ortho right of the vector now a new position should be 
             // the vector you need.. hopefully this helps 
             
    }
        }
```

PS: new here will work on haveing the editor open and give more concrete code soon